# Html forms to SQL build helper

Tags: sql, html, forms

Is there any lib (javascript, python, perl, java) which will help me to build html forms, and then after submit convert it to SQL language?

I mean if i have int field in db, i want to automatic builf form and  with int validation and after submiting it will create sql like `AND filed_name=value`. or SET field in db build to checkboxes and convert it to SQL `WHERE myset = 'Travel,Sports'` and so on... :)

Answer (score 0):

There are potential problems with something like that.  First you are putting yourself in danger of SQL injection by allowing field content to be directly added to a SQL command/query.  It would be better to have it use stored procedures or at least parse it through a filter/function of some kind.

Second, every database has it's own quirks, so you'd need to still adjust the auto-build features to match the database and version you are using for syntax and type.  Plus anything else like whether a bit or boolean should be represented by a checkbox, or a yes/no dropdown, or a radio button.

By the time you get done you'd probably be happier just building a database tier that you can pass your information into and handle how you like.

Comment: i am aware of all these problems, but it will be used in intranet no one will try to sql injection :)

Comment: I just want to be able to build fast WHERE sql statment when my Buisness Unit will invent new requirements